# The method of "Mathematical Induction" as explained in my book.

Tags: logic, soft-question

I am reading the book "A Treatise on Advanced Calculus" by  Philip Franklin. I found this book in our city's central library and liked it at the first reading, am continuing this book as a reference. I got some confusion at the very first topic ["Mathematical Induction"](https://archive.org/stream/ATreatiseOnAdvancedCalculus/Franklin-ATreatiseOnAdvancedCalculus#page/n13/mode/2up). I am familiar with mathematical induction pretty much but I could not grasp the way author explained it.
In the link i given $-$ After introduction the first topic starts. It is divided in $8$ small paragraphs. I understand $7$ paragraphs out of these. I have confusion in the $3$rd paragraph which I am quoting here:

> "If each of the members of $I$, an infinite collection of positive integers, is 
>   less than, or equal to, $N$, every integer of the collection $I$ is equal to some 
>   member of the finite collection $1, 2, .\ .\ . N$ Thus there is a finite collection of distinct integers, $F$, such that each member of $I$ is equal to a 
>   member of $F$. The greatest integer of $F$ is the greatest of $I$, so that the 
>   first collection $I$ has a greatest integer."

The two points on which I have trouble are as follows:

1. How this paragraph satiates(offsets) the whole article, that is what is the purpose of this paragraph. In other words what is the logic provided by this paragraph which is necessary for an apt understanding of the remaining article. What is the benefit of assuming that $I$ has a greatest integer.
2. Why the author assumes that $I$, an infinite collection of positive integers, has an upperbound(a greatest number)?  We know that $I$ is an infinite set so has not any greatest integer. Moreover how can we disprove this argument, that is does it directly follows from the definition of $I$ that it does not have a greatest integer or it can be proved in a mathematical way?

I understood the remaining $7$ paragraphs. I am not able to understand what the author is trying to convey in this $3$rd paragraph that I quoted.

Comment: Basically the author want to prove the principle of *mathematical induction* (often assumed as an *axiom*) as a *theorem*; for doing so, he states some "more basic" principles which (as argued by Joshua in his answer) he assumes that are "more intuitive" than the theorem he want to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We didn't assume that the elements in $I$ are all distinct. In essence, this paragraph argues the proposition: *any bounded set of positive integers can only contain finitely many distinct elements*, without assuming *a priori* that $I$ is finite.

This has the immediate, significant corollary that *every bounded set of positive integers has a greatest element*.

This is all fairly intuitive, so such an approach may seem unnecessary. Still, one could argue that it clears up some ambiguities that might crop up along the line. Consider for example a bounded sequence taking values in $\mathbb{N}$ - the above discussion shows that the sequence can only take finitely many values. This is fairly immediate, but arguably non-trivial, as it is related to the properties of the natural numbers - if we consider a bounded sequence taking values in $\mathbb{Q}$ or in $\mathbb{R}$, we cannot draw the same conclusion.

Note that the notions of **greatest element** and **least upper bound** are distinct in general. (Consider for example the set $[0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$. This has a least upper bound, namely 1, but does not have a greatest element.) The fact that they coincide for finite subsets of the natural numbers is an important statement about the nature of the natural numbers, and is closely related to induction.

One additional comment that occurs to me is that the terminology used by the author is highly suggestive. By an infinite *set*, we would usually understand a set with infinitely many distinct elements, as the definition of "set" usually doesn't allow repeated elements. However, the author of your article was careful to speak of an infinite *collection* of natural numbers, which does not carry the same connotation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think i did not read the article contemplatively. The main thing is that i misunderstood $I$ as a set of all postive integers $Z^{+}$.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're actually making this mistake, but note that you can have an infinite set of distinct integers in $\mathbb{Z}$ that is bounded above. In your article, and indeed in general whenever we start talking about induction, we restrict attention to *positive* integers, i.e. integers in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Ah, I see that you have edited your comment to remove the ambiguity that I commented on above. Cleary you weren't making the mistake I alluded to :).

Comment: I do not quite understand your example: "...a bounded sequence taking values in $\mathbb{N}$... ". You say:"_the sequence can only take finitely many values_"- What do we mean by the **value** of a sequence? Secondly In $\mathbb{Q}$ or in $\mathbb{R}$ why we cannot draw the same conclusion?. Third We can prove _mathematical induction_ by proving "_any non-empty collection of positive integers contains a least integer_" then what is the need of proving "_every bounded set of positive integers has a greatest element._"

Comment: A sequence $(x_n)$ takes a value $a$ if $x_k=a$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. For example, a constant sequence only takes one value. For your second question, there exist sequences in $\mathbb{Q}$ (and hence in $\mathbb{R}$) that are bounded, yet still take infinitely many different values. Consider for example $x_n = 1/n \in \mathbb{Q}$. For your third question, we do not need this result in order to establish induction. However, it is informative in the sense that it tells us something about the nature of $\mathbb{N}$ that intuitively justifies the induction domino effect.

Comment: I don't think that it's too helpful to dwell on why we "need" this proposition. I would simply think of it as an attempt to express what's so special and so simple about $\mathbb{N}$ in contrast to more complex sets like $\mathbb{Q}$ - something that we intuitively already have an excellent grasp of. As such, it's more of an observation than a "result".

Comment: Are you saying mathematical-induction is an observation? The book clearly mentions that _mathematical-induction_ is a _consequence_.

Comment: I mean the greatest element result is an observation.

Comment: Can we prove somehow that "$I$ has a greatest integer?" OR it is an axiom? Indeed when i wrote my question i was in an impression that $I$ is a set so it shouldn't have a greatest element. Now i understand that $I$ has not all distinct elements.

Comment: Should i edit my question? In my question i am asking for a disprove but i should ask for a prove(and i want to). In the quoted paragraph the author says:"_If each of the members of $I$, an infinite collection of positive integers, is less than, or equal to, $N$"_ this directly implies that $N$ is the greatest element so we defined $I$ in such a way that $N$ is assumed to be its greatest number then why the author compared $I$ with $F$ to show $N$ is the greatest element. I am new to mathematics please pardon me for these type of questions.

Comment: Whether "$I$ has a greatest integer" is an axiom or a theorem will depend on how you set things up - there are several ways to do it. In this case, the author seems to be using the fact/observation that every finite collection of integers has a greatest integer as an axiom, from which he deduces that $I$ (a bounded collection of integers) has a greatest integer. This treatment is potentially slightly less rigorous than the usual way to do things - in most modern treatments we take induction as an axiom, and prove everything else from that.

Comment: $N$ is not assumed to be the greatest member of $I$. Instead, we assumed that $I$ is *bounded* by $N$, which means that all of the elements of $N$ considered individually are smaller than $N$.

Comment: Also, we do not conclude that $N$ is the greatest element of $I$, but instead that $I$ *has* a (non-specified) greatest element. Indeed, the collection $A = \{1, 1, 2\}$ is bounded by $N = 435$, but its greatest element is $2$.

Comment: What i got is this: The author takes the axiom-"_Every non-empty finite collection of positive integers has a greatest integer_" right? And then from this axiom he deduce the fact/theorem that:"_Every infinite collection of positive integers has a greatest integer if it is bounded above_".

Comment: That's correct, yes.